# Date picker event for tooltip data

Tags: php, datepicker

I am trying to show data in tool tip from database after selecting date range from calendar dynamically.

My code is as below

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
include "connect.php";

$sql="select * from table_records where rec_time between '$startdate' and   'enddate'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$message="Total Fee ".$row["fee"]."\nTotal Time ".$row["fee"];


?>
<table>
<tr title="<?php echo $message; ?>">
<td>
<input type='date' name='stardate'/>
<td><td>
<input type='date' name='enddate'/>
</td></tr>
</body>
```

in above code i want to get the data from database when user select diofferent data range and show that data in tool tip or in title of . Please help

Comment: `$sql="select * from table_records where $rec_time between '$startdate' and   'enddate'";` enddate what?? this is column name `$rec_time`? where you define these variables? what is it? `ysql_fetch_assoc`? do u know mysql_* is closed in php 7? lot of html missing

Comment: I don't see any where you wrote any code related to tooltip.

Comment: Or a form to submit the selected dates.

Comment: @devpro I want those two variables from datepicker whenever they change

Comment: First of all, get rid of `mysql_*` functions, it's 2016!!! Move to PDO. Secondly you should get an idea about `dates` and how to query them. You have big syntax errors that should should be fixed.